# How to bind movement keys to an object in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want an object to move around with WASD; I know macros can do that, but idk exactly how.

I tried to start with only the D key so I could see if that worked, and I asked Claude AI to do it, but it only managed to make a script that makes a square move right 10 pixels whenever I clicked it instead of when I pressed D:

```
Sub CrearCuadradoYMoverlo()
    'Crear un cuadrado en la diapositiva activa
    Dim sld As Slide
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 50, 50, 100, 100)
    shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 

    'Asignar el movimiento del cuadrado a la tecla "D"
    sld.Shapes(1).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = ppActionRunMacro
    sld.Shapes(1).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Run = "MoverCuadrado"
End Sub

Sub MoverCuadrado()
    'Mover el cuadrado 10 pixeles a la derecha 
    Dim sld As Slide
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    sld.Shapes(1).Left = sld.Shapes(1).Left + 10
End Sub
```

(sorry for Spanish notes)

If someone could make a script for me to move it everywhere with WASD I'd be so glad

Comment: >> "If someone could make a script for me"  StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. People will help solve problems with code you've already written but not write it for you (or fix the junk code that ChatGPT and other AIs create).  By the way, your code example moves the square in *points* (1" = 72 points), not pixels.